# егэ по информатике номер 25

Tags: python

Найти минимальный элемент в массиве, который делится на 4, а потом все элементы, делящиеся на 4 поменять на этот минимальный

```
for i in range(0, n):
    a.append(int(input()))
j = min(k for k in a if k%4 == 0)
for i in range(n):
    if a[i]%4 == 0:
        a[i] = j
    print(a[i])
```

Comment: Получил баранку

Comment: В чем заключается вопрос?

Comment: @Эникейщик почему «получил баранку», видимо

Comment: Что не так в программе?

Comment: @artem вроде всё так, если переменные `a` и `n` изначально даны

Comment: @andreymal то есть стоит делать апелляцию?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо инициализировать переменные `n` и `a`.

Затем я маленько изменил вашу программу (которая работает хорошо), чтобы печатала список `a` как после ввода его елементов, так после его изменения:

```
n = 10
a = []

for i in range(0, n):
    a.append(int(input()))
print(a)

j = min(k for k in a if k%4 == 0)
for i in range(n):
    if a[i]%4 == 0:
        a[i] = j
print(a)
```

Пример вывода:

> [1, 9, 4, 8, 12, 6, 5, 16, 1, 1]
>   [1, 9, 4, 4, 4, 6, 5, 4, 1, 1]

Comment: В ЕГЭ эти переменные вроде обычно даны изначально